# How to download the latest binary release from github?

Tags: bash, github

I want to download the two (.bin and .zip) binaries from the latest releases.

I tried using the following command

```
curl -s https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/latest | grep "browser_download_url.*zip" | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d "\" | wget -qi -
```

but nothing happens, output being `SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc`

I'm open to using any other (wget, ecurl etc) commands.

Comment: You dropped a quote in your `tr` command. It probably should be `tr -d "\"`

Comment: After looking over it a second time, there are so many things wrong with that command. You might want to start by testing your `curl` command first, if it works proceed by adding the `grep` part and then continue to get the desired output.

Comment: I see. I got the command from here: https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8#file-one-liner-to-download-the-latest-release-from-github-repo-md

Comment: Try using instead Github's REST API for getting the latest release (see the curl example and the response with all the URLs): https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#get-the-latest-release

Comment: Gino, can you point out which command you have in mind? I have to admit I am totally lost within this documentation.

Comment: @RedSeal2 the `curl` command you are asking for is right on the bottom of your screen if you click the link he provided without scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Is it trying to extract the download link from the HTML page? That's error prone and may break any time.

For such operations, check if they offer an API first.

They do: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#get-the-latest-release

You could write something like (pseudo code):

```sh
 curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/latest \
    | jq .assets[0].browser_download_url \
    | xargs wget -qi -
```

Like suggested in the comments, test each command (pipe separated) individually.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli), specifically the [`release download`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download) command:

```sh
gh release download --repo Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere --pattern '*.bin'
gh release download --repo Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere --archive zip
```

Without specifying a release tag, the command defaults to the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Just running curl on the url gives this:

```sh
curl https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/latest
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/tag/1.2.6">redirected</a>.</body>
```

So, you easily see something is amiss straight off. Checking the curl help, you find options, command below to pinpoint what you need:

```sh
curl --help | grep redirect
 -L, --location      Follow redirects
     --max-redirs <num> Maximum number of redirects allowed
     --proto-redir <protocols> Enable/disable PROTOCOLS on redirect
     --stderr        Where to redirect stderr
```

First clue is `redirect` in the response and then we see in the help section that there is a flag to handle that.

Running it with th `-L` command gives the expected output. Pipeing it to `grep "browser_download_url.*zip"` however gives you nothing. You then investigate to see what the right match would be. But let's try mathing just html link with zip, just to see what happens.

```sh
curl -sL https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/latest | grep "href=.*zip"
          <a href="/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/download/1.2.6/atmosphere-1.2.6-master-173d5c2d3+hbl-2.4.1+hbmenu-3.5.0.zip" rel="nofollow" data-skip-pjax>
          <a href="/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/archive/refs/tags/1.2.6.zip" rel="nofollow" data-skip-pjax>
```

From there you can probably find what you are after to construct your command. As you see, links are relative with this method, so you still have to provide the base url to `wget` (or a `curl` equivalent) to finally be able to dowload what you are after.

This is more a reply to get you going on trouble shooting. You already have other answers to actually do what you want. But if you can't install the tools suggested, you could probably do something like this:

```sh
curl -sL https://github.com/Atmosphere-NX/Atmosphere/releases/latest |
    awk '/releases\/download/ && done != 1 {
        sub(/.*href="/, "https://github.com")
        sub(/".*/, "")
        print
        done = 1
    }' |
    xargs curl -LsO
```

Not suggesting this is a good way, just a way.